# Converting string array to char array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, to-char

I want to read .txt file, extract every distinct from it and save it to array. So far I came up with this:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\szyfrowanie\TextSample.txt");
string uniqueLetters = new string(text.Distinct().ToArray());
```

I couldn't find any way to save those distinct letters to a char array. Now I want to convert the `uniqueLetters` array to a `char` array. I've been trying through certain things like creating a new `char[]` array and assigning `uniqueLetter` value in a `for` loop. `ToCharArray()` also failed me. Does anybody have any ideas how to do it?

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is. `text.Distinct().ToArray()` should already return a `char[]`. Why don't you use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ToArray` method returns a `char[]`, that is, a `char` array. Use it like this in your code:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\szyfrowanie\TextSample.txt");
        char[] uniqueLetters = text.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value type is char array and not string.

```
string text = "AABBCC";
var uniqueLetters = text.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Output (array of chars):

A, B, C.

Edit:
Dont forget:

```
using System.Linq;
```